# Window-based clients to Fedora Directory Services

Tags: active-directory

Is there any way to have user login in window-based client machines to authenticate with Fedora Directory Services?

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the [Howtos for integrating Samba with the 389 / Fedora Directory Server](http://directory.fedoraproject.org/wiki/Howto:Samba)?
You would basically need to run Samba in NT4 domain controller mode and join your Windows workstations to the domain - just as you would have done with a Windows domain.

Comment: Thanks syneticon-dj for your reply. I am not aware of the integration of Samba with 389/FDS. I'm trying to link all my Windows workstation (running Vista) to FDS. Btw, if I'm able to do that, am I able to restrict user privileges in the workstations, e.g. group policy?

Comment: Samba 3 does not support group policies, it just supports [NT4-style policies](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/PolicyMgmt.html) which often can do similar things.  Support for Windows 2000-Style group policies is introduced with [Samba 4](http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba4/HOWTO), but this version comes with an own directory server with functionality similar to AD's.